# Can we add "results found on these sites" and "sort by time" function to "search all sites"?

Tags: feature-request, search

When searching all sites on StackExchange, sometimes the returned results are too many. I wonder if we can add the following function:

- results found on these sites: so it gives a summary for the current search keyword which sites contain results and which not. Just some lines of icon is enough. I find this function helpful because perhaps for historical reasons, the topics of some sites are overlapping. For example, I can find EE related questions both on "Stack Overflow" and "Electrical Engineering", and also I can find CS questions (specific questions on vim/linux/etc.) on "Stack Overflow", "Super User", "ask ubuntu", and ... With this function, there's no need for me to open each site and search.
- sort by time: I find the time of each returned result record seems ...random. I don't know why. Can I sort the results so I can check the latest ones?

Comment: It is only a workaround, but you can use the [search modifier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) *created* to get only the recent result. For example, [created:2020-08-01..](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=covid+created%3A2020-08-01..) restricts the search to the post created since the beginning of this month. (Or you can use *lastactive* instead of created, if that is what you're after.)

Comment: @Martin Oh, I forgot this. I'v only used `[]` and `is:` modifiers so far.